# MS access mdb file has a "repair" status first time it is opened from Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I have created an .mdb file programatically from another .mdb file using VBScript. It creates a table in the second .mdb file and populates data. Everything works fine and data is populated correctly. This is done using JET 4.0 driver.

The issue is that when I try to open the .mdb file using Access 2007, it tries to repair the file first. I do not know why that is happening. If I try to open it in Access 2003, it opens without the repair. I need to fix this. Has anyone run into this before or any ideas as to why it is happening?

Comment: I don't think this is programming related, maybe a question for superuser?

Comment: I think this is programming related. I'm creating the second .mdb file using VBscript and I'm doing something wrong while creating or copying data. I'm thinking why would a clean .mdb file need to be repaired.

Comment: I have created an mdb just now in VBScript and opened it using Access 2010 without any problems. Perhaps you could post the line(s) you use to create the mdb?

Comment: Hi Remou, thanks for your response. I'm trying out a couple of things. If it still does not work, i'll post the code by the end of the day. Thanks again!

Comment: How in the world could somebody think this is not programming related? Do you think receptionists routinely write vbScript with DDL commands?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the mdb that needs to be repaired? Or is it the windows installer loading up and trying to repair MS Access?

MSAccess has some issues running multiple versions on one machine, look for "Windows Installer messages in Access" [on this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928091). The repair process is controlled by [various registry entries](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Access/microsoft.public.access.formscoding/2008-09/msg01266.html) you may be able to create a process to reset these and prevent the repair process running.